# Backbone.js loading a template by parameter

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I would like to load a View and passing a parameter named : layout_version

I'm using JST as my template engine.

```
Views.BottomBarView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: ".l-bottom-bar",
    template: JST['templates/bottom_bar'],
    render: function(options) { 
        this.model.set("layoutVersion", options.layoutVersion);
        this.$el.html( this.template(this.model.toJSON()) );
        return this;
    }
});
```

The .jst file is as follows:

```
    {{ if (layoutVersion == 1) { }}

        <div class="bottom-bar-s-version">Other</div>

   {{ } else if { layoutVersion == 2 }}

        <div class="bottom-bar-s-version">Show more</div>

   {{ } }}
```

Since I'm not passing any model to the view when creating it, just an object { layoutVersion: 2 } I get `this.model` is undefined

I'm using the bottom_bar file to hold two different HTMLs inside one file and rendering it depending on the parameter inside the model.

How can I achieve my goal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pass a model, you can just pass an object to the template.

```
Views.BottomBarView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: ".l-bottom-bar",
  template: JST['templates/bottom_bar'],
  render: function(options) { 
    this.$el.html(this.template( { "layoutVersion": options.layoutVersion }));
    return this;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this `this.model.toJSON()` by :

```
{ "layoutVersion": options.layoutVersion }
```